# Cannot perform database rollback using REST-Assured and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest-assured

I created some integration test methods using Rest-Assured and this way I'm testing whether the correct objects get persisted to the database using `/../insert/` or not. 
The problem is I cannot find a way to delete the inserted data after the test finishes. `@Transactional` doesn't work as I'm not interacting with repositories and JPA.

So the main question is what is the best way to perform database rollbacks after a test method has inserted data?

Thanks.

Comment: `@Rollback` - http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/Rollback.html

Comment: @Rollback doesn't work either. It says this after the test is finished: Rolled back transaction for test context. But the data gets inserted.

Comment: We all know @Transactional works with repositories and JPA. So there are two way to solve this issue. 1. Use mock and do not store to db. 2. use in memory database such as h2.

Comment: How about using dbUnit? That way you can specify initial data for your tests if you need it and it is quite easy to set it up to perform "rollback" after every test. Or maybe @SQL annotation and call some your custom sql script that will delete data from tables.

Comment: Thank you all for your possible solutions. I finally solved it by using another database; only for performing tests. I found the Spring's annotation `@ActiveProfiles` quite useful for using other configurations.